# How do I mount to SAMBA drive on boot with raspberry pi?

Tags: boot, mount, samba

The only way I have managed to mount the drive is by typing the command:

```
> sudo mount -t cifs //"IP"/hdd1 /home/pi -o uid=1000,iocharset=utf8,username="USERNAME",password="PASSWORD",sec=ntlm
```

However, I have to do this every single time I reboot.

Can this command run automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Edit you fstab file:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/fstab
```

Add this line:

```
//"IP"/hdd1 /home/pi cifs uid=1000,_netdev,iocharset=utf8,defaults,rw,username=username,password=password 0 0
```

Save the file and reboot your Pi.  It should automatically mount the shared folder.

Comment: I thought this would work but it still didnt mount after reboot

Comment: Check /var/log/messages for errors related to the mount; or, to verify the entry, type "sudo mount /home/pi" after rebooting -- if the entry is set up correctly, it should mount; if not, you may get a message indicating the problem.